# open window pdf using java or javascript for aplications windows 8

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, windows-8

how do I open another program using javascritp or java application on a Windows 8

I need to open an external program from my application windows 8

Comment: What kind of application?

Comment: Applications windows 8

Answer (score 0):

If it is an executable file (.exe, .com, .msi, etc.) then you can try something like this in its simplest form:

Here we are going to open Windows NotePAD:

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");
}
catch (IOException ex) { 
    //Do something here... 
}
```

**EDIT:**

There is a big difference between a Windows application and and a PDF file. This is generally why someone would ask "what you're trying to open". A PDF file is a associative file which means it can either be viewed or worked with through a particular executable application such as .txt files are viewed and worked with through the executable application named NotePAD.exe.

To view associative files in the Windows Operating System you need to make sure the associative file is actually registered (associated) with the particular application you desire. In your case you want to open a PDF file. Windows could have PDF files associated with a Viewer Only application which serves no purpose if the intent is to actually edit the PDF once it's in view as you would through Adobe Acrobat. You need to be clear on that since one system may be associated with one and another system associated with the other.

If you want to be specific about which application opens your particular PDF file then the first example I provided will work fine since almost all PDF viewers and editors will accept a command line which is where you can place the path to your particular PDF file. However if you are still insistent upon using the Windows current associated application then you could do it this way:

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    try {
        File myFile = new File("C:\\MyPDF_Files\\MyPDF.pdf");
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
    }
    catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException ex) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Either there is no application found "
          + "which is associatd with\nthe file you want to work with or the "
          + "file doesn't exist!\n\n"+ filePath, 
          "File Association Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you somewhat.

Comment: Good , but in my particular case open an external program like Adobe Reader to view a PDF

Comment: Edited my answer to accommodate what you need.

Comment: Sorry , can I expressed myself badly. I developed a Windows 8 application in javascript and need to open a pdf in it but I can not , ever used PDF.js with canvas and nothing . So surgui the idea of ​​using a program out of my application to open this pdf , that's what I need only see the pdf in my windows application 8.

Comment: Sorry Felipe, I have never used PDF.js  but you can get an example here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/helloworld